# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated work only with default animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, modalviewcontroller

I've a weird problem... in a tabbar application, in the tabBarController i call:

```
[myController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
self presentModalViewController:myController animated:YES];
```

myController get presented and everything work but when i try to dismiss it (from within myController) with:

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

It does the dismiss animation, i can almost see my tabBarController active view when suddenly myController re-appear. 
The only way to make it work is using the default transition style:

```
UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal
```

Every other animation, or even trying to dismiss myController without animations cause that problem.

After the dismiss call, viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear of myController get called.
viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear of myController DON'T get called when it re-appear.
Calling again the dismiss function does nothing.
I'm almost sure nothing is presenting myController again, it's like it's simply not going away completely.

I've tried replacing myController with a fresh new controller with and empty view, nothing changed.

It's sounds like a stupid problem but i really can't understand it...
PS: I'm using iOS5, storyboard, ARC, it's an iphone app, i'm using the simulator (can't try on an iphone at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

Is that dismiss being called from within the modally presented VC?  Try this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: yes it is, i've also tried [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; but the problem remains.